# Only get records that happened yesterday

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to only get records that happened the previous day using mongoose. I have the query below. But today's record is also included in the sum value. I will appreciate any opinion to achieve this.

```
const yesterday = new Date()
yesterday.setDate(yesterday.getDate() - 1)

const sums = salesSchema.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        createdAt: {
          $gte: yesterday,
          $lt: new Date()
        } // expected this should filter only createdAT previous day
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: null,
        total: { $sum: { $multiply: ["$price", "$quantity"] } } 
      }
    }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're using the current date as the upper limit in your `$match`, so it's including all records up to the current date.

Instead, you can work with 2 distinct dates:

```
const yesterdayStart = new Date();
yesterdayStart.setDate(yesterdayStart.getDate() - 1);
// Set to the start of yesterday
yesterdayStart.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

const yesterdayEnd = new Date();
yesterdayEnd.setDate(yesterdayEnd.getDate() - 1);
// Set to the end of yesterday
yesterdayEnd.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);

const sums = salesSchema.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      createdAt: {
        $gte: yesterdayStart,
        $lte: yesterdayEnd // Only include records up to the end of yesterday
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      total: { $sum: { $multiply: ["$price", "$quantity"] } }
    }
  }
]);
```